# Generic implicit class that applies both to Int and Long

Tags: scala

I wanted to create a "pimp my type" for natural numbers in Scala by adding some helper methods.

My first attempt was to create one for `Int` and one for `Long` (and later one for `BigInt` perhaps too)

```
  implicit class SuperInt(n:Int) {
    def square = n * n
    def pow(m: Int) = math.pow(n,m)
    def **(m: Int) = pow(m)
    def sqrt = math.sqrt(n)
    def isEven = dividesBy(2)
    def isOdd = !isEven
    def dividesBy(m:Int) = n % m == 0
  }

  implicit class SuperLong(n:Long) {
    def square = n * n
    def pow(m: Int) = math.pow(n,m)
    def **(m: Int) = pow(m)
    def sqrt = math.sqrt(n)
    def isEven = dividesBy(2)
    def isOdd = !isEven
    def dividesBy(m:Int) = n % m == 0
  }
```

Exactly the same code of course, not too DRY, and doesn't "feel" right.

**So my question is - what is the (idiomatic) Scala way to do this for Long, Int and BigInt all at once?**

---

p.s. Here is what I tried so far, it sort of works, but I'm pretty sure it's not idiomatic and has a lot of issues.

The following a result of reading a little bit about "type classes" [here](http://www.derekwyatt.org/2012/03/12/adding-squared-to-scala-numbers-with-implicts-and-type-classes/) (which I still don't fully feel I 100% understand) so this is the result (If your eyes hurt, please forgive me, I'm relatively new to Scala)

```
  implicit class SuperNumber[A : Numeric](i: A) {
    import Numeric.Implicits._
    def squared: A = i * i
    def pow(m: Int) = math.pow(i.toDouble(),m)
    def **(m: Int) = pow(m)
    def sqrt = math.sqrt(i.toDouble())
    def isEven = dividesBy(2)
    def isOdd = !isEven
    def dividesBy(m:Int) = {
      i match {
        case n @ (_:Int | _:Long) => n.toLong() % m == 0
        case other => {
          val asDouble = other.toDouble()
          val asLong = other.toLong()
          if (asDouble == asLong) {
            asLong % m == 0
          } else {
            false
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

(I added "support" for non Int and Long as it didn't seem too hard)

Comment: Keep in mind that anything with `Numeric` is going to be incredibly slow compared to primitives.  See spire for how to do this quickly.  It's not exactly trivial.  (Google scala spire.)

Comment: thanks, I guess that in this case, DRY can go out the window, and I can simply have a `trait SuperNum` that has `squared:Numeric` etc and override it with `squared:Long` for long etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have looks pretty close. A few comments:

The type class you want is `Integral`, not `Numeric`.

Instead of writing the context bound as `[A: Integral]`, put an implicit parameter on the constructor, so you can import `mkNumericOps` from that object:

```
implicit class SuperNumber[A](i: A)(implicit integral: Integral[A]) {

  import integral._
```

Comment: Thanks! is there a runtime performance price tag with this approach?

Comment: Yes, as far as I understand it. Because to evaluate `4.squared`, it will have to box the `int` as an `Int`, wrap that in a `SuperNumber` (which has two fields), then wrap it again with `IntegralOps` to do the multiplication. So that's three object instantiations. Now, what is the actual cost of this on a real JVM? I couldn't say (never speculate about performance without benchmarks...)